# Why is my .htaccess file redirecting me to 404?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have the following `.htaccess` file in my root:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .html .htm
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} maindomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.maindomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.maindomain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/es/(.*)$ http://es.maindomain.com/$1
</IfModule>
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.maindomain.com/404/
```

Then, in a subfolder (`/wp`) I have a WordPress install. But when I try to access `https://maindomain.com/seconddomain.com/wp/wp-admin` it redirects me to `maindomain.com/404/`

Should I remove all the RewriteRules? Any help would be great.

Here is the `.htaccess` code for the `seconddomain.com` WordPress installation which resides in the subdirectory `/wp`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /seconddomain.com/wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /seconddomain.com/wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Maybe something has been lost in your exemplification, but the directives you've posted would result in a redirect loop? How does the `seconddomain.com` subdirectory fit into this?

Comment: That first configuration file on root level contains some obvious errors. Not sure if those are just typos here, you need to make sure that you give precise details, not just something rough. Same with the URL `https://maindomain/seconddomain.com/wp/wp-admin` which does not really make sense.

Comment: Those were typos, I'm sorry.

Comment: Please confirm you have fixed all the "typos" (you made a subtle change in your ["new (duplicate) question"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71139326/i-have-redirect-problems-with-my-htaccess-files-it-sends-me-in-a-loop) that affects this). What is your file structure? Please edit your question to include this information. You mention that a site "resides in the subdirectory `/wp`", however, `seconddomain.com` also appears to be a subdirectory, not a hostname? Please confirm. In your "new (duplicate) question", you state that "it sends me in a loop" - what is the nature of this "loop"?

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have resolved the issue myself. I removed:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.maindomain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]